# Realm and Electron

Tags: reactjs, realm, electron

I want to send/receive messages from an Electron app to Realm.
I searched the web and found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-electron), but I don't know how to do it and I couldn't find an example.

Can I work with Realm and Electron? If so, can you show me a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not officially supported yet, but we have merged a change that seems to make it work. It's not released yet but it will be included in the next release that is due very soon.

Comment: Can I use Realm.js with Electron? Only on Linux and osX, but not Windows?

Comment: Yes, Realm is not supported on Windows in any shape or form at this moment, but we are working on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and work! I'll wait.